# Why I cannot modify the "Created" .... "Modified" columns after updating SP library file?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to replace file to SP library without modify any metadata. Therefore i am trying to get those value before replacing the file and then update those value the original.

However, all error :(

> The catch block said that The XXXX file has been modified by AAA on
>   BBB

```
byte[] fileData= doc.File.OpenBinary(SPOpenBinaryOptions.None); // to download the file from SharePoint in byte[] format

.......

DateTime created = (DateTime)doc["Created"];
DateTime modified = (DateTime)doc["Modified"];
string author = (string)doc["Author"];
string editor = (string)doc["Editor"];
web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(itemsite, itemSubsite, fileURL), fileData, true); // replace my new file to SP library
Console.WriteLine("editor: " + editor);
doc["Created"] = created;
doc["Author"] = author;
doc["Modified"] = modified;
doc["Editor"] = editor;
doc.Update();// error
```

However, if i don't modify the Created .. modified column:

```
 byte[] fileData= doc.File.OpenBinary(SPOpenBinaryOptions.None);
 .......
web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(itemsite, itemSubsite, fileURL), fileData, true);
// Done, but the modify name will be changed to mine
```

Or if i don't edit my file and just modify the Created .. modified column:

```
DateTime created = (DateTime)doc["Created"];
DateTime modified = (DateTime)doc["Modified"];
string author = (string)doc["Author"];
string editor = (string)doc["Editor"];

doc["Created"] = created;
doc["Author"] = author;
doc["Modified"] = modified;
doc["Editor"] = editor;
doc.Update();
//Done, but the file never been edited.
```

So, why upload file and update metaData cannot mix together?

**Update**

```
SPListItemCollection items = getListItemCollection(oSPWeb, itemlibName);
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++ )
{
var doc = items[i];
byte[] fileData = doc.File.OpenBinary(SPOpenBinaryOptions.None);
........
DateTime created = (DateTime)doc["Created"];
DateTime modified = (DateTime)doc["Modified"];
string author = (string)doc["Author"];
string editor = (string)doc["Editor"]; //StaffA

oSPWeb.Files.Add(Path.Combine(itemsite, itemSubsite, fileURL), fileData, true); // replace my new file to SP library

SPListItemCollection itemForUpdate = getListItemCollection(oSPWeb,  itemlibName);            
itemForUpdate[i]["Created"] = created;
itemForUpdate[i]["Author"] = author;
itemForUpdate[i]["Modified"] = modified;
itemForUpdate[i]["Editor"] = editor;
itemForUpdate[i].Update();

string neweditor = (string)uploadedFiles[i]["Editor"]; // change to my name
}
```

Comment: have you tried my new code ?

Answer (score 7):

Considering that You are replacing file to SP library using custom code.

If you want to replace file to SP library without modifying Created/Modified by and time stamps, you can use `item.SystemUpdate()` instead of `item.Update()`

As per your comment and code, you will need to do following changes:

```
SPFile file = web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(itemsite, itemSubsite, fileURL), fileData, true);
SPListItem item = file.Item;
item.SystemUpdate();
```

Comment: sorry, with `web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(itemsite, itemSubsite, fileURL), fileData, true);` i do not need to use any `item.update() / item.SystemUpdate() `.. However, it will auto edit the editor columns

Comment: fail.. it changes to my name, not the original

Comment: I hope you are overwriting document, and not uploading new

Comment: i am replacing. In fact, the "Created By" column of the item which i try your way is still keeping the original

Comment: let me re-write full code for you

Comment: I guess the  `SPFile file = web.Files.Add(...)` will update the "Modified" column too.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to update an old object and since you have already uploaded new file, it will give conflict error

Try this one

```
 byte[] fileData= doc.File.OpenBinary(SPOpenBinaryOptions.None); // to download the file from SharePoint in byte[] format

    .......

DateTime created = (DateTime)doc["Created"];
DateTime modified = (DateTime)doc["Modified"];
string author = (string)doc["Author"];
string editor = (string)doc["Editor"];
web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(itemsite, itemSubsite, fileURL), fileData, true); // replace my new file to SP library
Console.WriteLine("editor: " + editor);

doc=list.{Load your Item again}//load doc item again to get updated item.
    doc["Created"] = created;
    doc["Author"] = author;
    doc["Modified"] = modified;
    doc["Editor"] = editor;
    doc.Update();
```

Comment: The `doc.Update();` under web.files.add will bring error to me.

Comment: First run this part of code........ byte[] fileData= doc.File.OpenBinary(SPOpenBinaryOptions.None);
 .......
web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(itemsite, itemSubsite, fileURL), fileData, true);
// Done, but the modify name will be changed to mine

Comment: then load updated item again

Comment: then modify....doc["Created"] = created;
doc["Author"] = author;
doc["Modified"] = modified;
doc["Editor"] = editor;
doc.Update();

Comment: it's working for me

Comment: I have updated my post. Could you please tell me why the editor is still changed to mine instead of original? Thank you very much.